# Remove small image from a larger image, where the larger image contains the small image in what might look like a water mark or noice

Tags: python, opencv, deep-learning, computer-vision, artificial-intelligence

The idea is that the small image is superimposed on the large or original one, so I want to remove the small image and refill the space.
Tried multiple solutions, but most of them are outdated and I am unable to solve them on google colab.
One solution was

```
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv
img = cv.imread('messi_2.jpg')
mask = cv.imread('mask2.png', cv.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
dst = cv.inpaint(img,mask,3,cv.INPAINT_TELEA)
cv.imshow('dst',dst)
cv.waitKey(0)
cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

From OpenCV documentation, but it didn't work for me and kept giving the error that the images' size is different, which is obvious but I am unable to solve.
Resizing the image will make it larger, which is not the same as it would be placed in the original image, and especially since it might contain any color, it is difficult to minimize things to only black and white.

I thought of filling up the image with black pixels until it reaches the same size, but that was inapplicable, especially for a model I would have to test its accuracy with something like SSIM.

Any help?

Using cv.inpaint but with imgs diff size and no rescaling

Comment: You would need to "locate" the mask in the image first. If you know that the scale of your mask is exactly the same as it appears in your image, then you can likely just use template matching which will help you locate the region of the image. Then you can simply inpaint on that region of the image.

Comment: @alkasm no sadly the scale wouldn't always be the same. All I know is that the orientation of the patch is multiplies of 90 degrees.The patch is an image that has been superimposed onto the base image at an arbitrary
location and size.

Comment: Then you'd need to basically do "scale invariant template matching" to find it. You can do this naively by creating many scaled versions of your text and trying template matching multiple times and picking the best result. Or, you could go for an approach with feature matching or similar. I'd suggest searching up "how to find a smaller image inside a larger one" as a subproblem to solve first. Once you have it, you should be able to inpaint on the ROI containing the template.

Comment: [mre] requires input data. show us the pictures.